# F# Unity Design-Time Configuration

Tags: dependency-injection, f#, unity-container, design-time

can make it work in C#:

- create C# console app named UnityCSharp
- add Unity NuGet
- reference System.Configuration
- add App.config and C# code as below, it works OK

App.config for C#:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="unity" type="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.UnityConfigurationSection, Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration"/>
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
  <unity xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/practices/2010/unity">
    <alias alias="myAlias" type="UnityCSharp.ILogger, UnityCSharp" />
    <container>
      <register type="myAlias" mapTo="UnityCSharp.Logger, UnityCSharp" />
      <register type="myAlias" mapTo="UnityCSharp.SpecialLogger, UnityCSharp" name="special" />
    </container>
  </unity>
</configuration>
```

C#:

```cs
using System;
using Microsoft.Practices.Unity;
using Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration;

namespace UnityCSharp
{
    public interface ILogger { string SayHello(); }
    public class Logger : ILogger { public string SayHello() { return "hello"; } }
    public class SpecialLogger : ILogger { public string SayHello() { return "special hello"; } }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var container = new UnityContainer().LoadConfiguration();
            Console.WriteLine(container.Resolve<ILogger>().SayHello()); // --> "hello"
            Console.WriteLine(container.Resolve<ILogger>("special").SayHello()); // --> "special hello"
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

But cannot repeat it in F# (again console app, named UnityFSharp, the same NuGet and System.Configuration reference).

App.config for F#:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="unity" type="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.UnityConfigurationSection, Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration"/>
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
  <unity xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/practices/2010/unity">
    <alias alias="myAlias" type="UnityFSharp.ILogger, UnityFSharp" />
    <container>
      <register type="myAlias" mapTo="UnityFSharp.Logger, UnityFSharp" />
      <register type="myAlias" mapTo="UnityFSharp.SpecialLogger, UnityFSharp" name="special" />
    </container>
  </unity>
</configuration>
```

F#:

```
open System;
open Microsoft.Practices.Unity
open Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration

type ILogger = abstract SayHello : unit -> string
type Logger() = interface ILogger with member x.SayHello () = "hello"
type SpecialLogger() = interface ILogger with member x.SayHello () = "special hello"

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    let container = (new UnityContainer()).LoadConfiguration() // CRASHES HERE
    Console.WriteLine (container.Resolve<ILogger>().SayHello()) // --> "hello"
    Console.WriteLine (container.Resolve<ILogger>("special").SayHello()) // --> "special hello"
    Console.ReadLine() |> ignore
    0
```

Would fail with:

> The type name or alias myAlias could not be resolved. Please check
>   your configuration file and verify this type name.

I understand the namings go differently in F# (http://ilspy.net/ screenshot below).
But how exactly can I make it work?
I have tried various F# modules, namespaces and App.config versions.
Just one working example would help! (I can reorganize my F#)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way the types are defined here, they compile into types called

- `Program+ILogger`
- `Program+Logger`
- `Program+SpecialLogger`

because they're defined in the `Program` module.

One option is to edit the configuration file to match the names:

```
<alias alias="myAlias" type="Program+ILogger, UnityFSharp" />
<container>
  <register type="myAlias" mapTo="Program+Logger, UnityFSharp" />
  <register type="myAlias" mapTo="Program+SpecialLogger, UnityFSharp" name="special" />
</container>
```

The way I figured that out was to add a line to the program before it crashed:

```
Console.WriteLine typeof<ILogger>
```

If you don't like those module names, you can put the types in proper namespaces:

```
namespace Ploeh.Samples

type ILogger = abstract SayHello : unit -> string
type Logger() = interface ILogger with member x.SayHello () = "hello"
type SpecialLogger() = interface ILogger with member x.SayHello () = "special hello"
```

However, that'll involve putting them in a separate file, as the `main` function is defined in the `Program` module. With the above namespace, the names become:

- `Ploeh.Samples.ILogger`
- `Ploeh.Samples.Logger`
- `Ploeh.Samples.SpecialLogger`

Comment: Thank you, Mark! Both of the ways you describe work nicely! "WriteLine typeof" was a clever thing to do. (tiny typo in your fist copy&paste: Program+ILogger --> Program+Logger on the 2nd occasion)